# 17.10: How to get the right version of Emacs when searching for it?

Tags: 17.10, emacs, gnome-shell

[image]

I regularly use Emacs and I have gotten used to on my Mac to just search for the first few characters and hit enter.   Doing this for Emacs - typing "emacs" - has worked well on Ubuntu too until I upgraded to 17.10.

As you can see on the image I get two identical icons so I don't know which one is the one I actually *want*, as the only difference is (GUI) and (Terminal) as indicated in the "Software" section below, and the text is truncated before that.  It appears that *both* are provided by the "emacs25" package, so I cannot just uninstall an obscure package to get rid of the Terminal version.

Which subtle changes can I do to fix this?  Either get rid of one, changing the icon, or make more of the text visible?

(Note that this is just the launcher and eye-candy.  I'm fine with typing "emacs -nw" on the command line if I need that.)

Comment: This is tagged [tag:unity-dash], but looks like [tag:gnome-shell].

Comment: The Emacs icons are shown in alphabetical order so click the first swirly E icon, GNU Emacs 25 (GUI), instead of the second swirly E icon which is GNU Emacs 25 (Terminal).

Comment: @muru  Thanks.  I didn't know that.  Retagged.